# How does Byzantine Reliable Broadcast ensure that each correct process eventually delivers a message?

Tags: process, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I don't understand how Byzantine Reliable Broadcast ensures with its totality property that if some message is delivered by any correct process, every correct process eventually delivers a message. 
In the case where the sender is correct I understand how Byzantine Reliable Broadcast works but if the sender is byzantine I don't. 
For example consider a scenario where there are four processes: A, B, C and D and A is the byzantine sender, so we respect the constraint that the total number of processes N (that is 4) is greater than three times the number of faulty processes f (that is 3f = 3). Now if A sends a message m only to B and C, how does Byzantine Reliable Broadcast ensure that also D delivers the message m?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is...

> Given four processes(N=4, f=1):A, B, C, D; and A is Byzantine faulty node, 
>   if A sends a message m only to B and C, how does Byzantine Reliable Broadcast ensure that also D delivers the message m?

Before answering your question, let me be clear one thing. Why are you considering D delivers the message m? I mean, totality property only says that "***If some message is delivered by any correct process***, then every correct
process eventually delivers a message." In your scenario, both B and C doesn't deliver the message m yet. So D doesn't need to be ensured that m is delivered.

But if your intention is to ask about how to achieve consistency among correct processes even in the situation where Byzantine sender sends different messages to different processes, I can answer that.

That's because B and C broadcast the message sent from A to verify that A is actually Byzantine sender or not. And then, the situation that D doesn't received the message from A is resolved because both B and C are assumed correct.

If you look at the detailed protocol of Byzantine reliable broadcast, there are two more steps that you didn't mention in your question. So, If C doesn't receive any message from the sender in first phase, C will know the fact in second phase because both B and C will broadcast the message and try to gather the 2f+1 number(quorum) of matching message.